# How to set VS2010 SQL table column to be unique?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

In Microsoft SQL Server 10, how do I set constraint, that column in table with data type nchar(50) must be unique?

Comment: is SQL Server 10 the same thing as SQL Server 2008?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
ALTER TABLE yourtable
  ADD CONSTRAINT yourColumn
  UNIQUE (uniqueConstraintName)
```

Comment: Thanks to this, I actually found http://databases.about.com/od/sqlserver/a/unique.htm what solved my problem.